# Add $mdDialog to angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

there i want to apply $mdDialog to the following angular function and I'm using angularjs 1.6.4. $mdDialog should prompt a message to select Yes or no to delete the file. Here is my code

```
$scope.deleteFile = function (key) {
                    $scope.documentEventText = "Document Deleted";
                    FileResourceService.deleteFile('KeyPhotos', key, $state.params.propertyId, $scope.key.id, $scope.getFiles);
                }
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the dialog inside the function as follows,

```
 var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
    })
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
      $scope.status = 'Confirmed';
    }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/WdOqRe)**